# How can I kick a certain user after someone typed a specific message

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on ('message', message =>{

   if (message.content === ("test")) {

    message.guild.members.get("their id").kick(); //ive seen this online but i
                                                  //dont know how to set up this guild thing
```

So when someone types test a specific user should be kicked

Comment: Wdym you don't know how to set up "this guild thing"?

Comment: I don't know but the command doesnt work and it seems like i missed something about it

Comment: Show the error, it's probably that you didn't replace "their id" with an id.

Comment: message.guild.members.get(Id).kick();
                          ^

TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function (instead of id i typed the actual id so the number of the user

Answer (score 1):

Giuliopime I don't know why I can't comment anymore. Just wanted to say thanks for your help it works!

Answer (score 0):

To kick a specific member you need to get him from the guild.members.cache.

So:

```
if(message.content === 'test' && message.channel.type === 'text'){
   message.guild.members.cache.get('ID of the member to kick').kick();
}
```

The `message.channel.type === 'text'` is there to prevent the bot from breaking when it receives the 'test' message in DMs, because if it receives it in DMs, it's not able to get the `message.guild`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont want to kick the user that typed the message. I want to kick a specific one

Comment: Feel free to upvote if this solved your issue @Thatsmycarnow12